bad thermocouple?
I just bought an outdoor/patio propane heater... the kind that looks kind of like a floor lamp. I am able to light it by pushing in the knob and turning it to activate the igniter. Per the instructions, I keep he knob pushed in for 30 seconds (I've gone as long as 2 minutes) and then let it go. As soon as I let it go, the gas cuts out and both the pilot and the main flame go out.
Everything I've found on Google and YouTube points to a dirty thermocouple, but this looks pretty pristine to me, no?

Is it possible that is was wired incorrectly when assembled? Or are they sometimes just faulty from the get? Any other suggestions for what I might investigate that doesn't involve a full dismantle (I'm disabled and don't have full use of my hands - getting to the point shown in the pic to inspect the thermocouple was a pretty big feat in and of itself)?
Thanks!!

Thermocouples  create very low voltage. If the connections are the least bit loose or corroded, there's not enough current flowing to hold the valve open. However -- it's brand new, so I'd return it.

Yes, take it back for a replacement. It apparently has a bad thermocouple.
